# Processing binary data from files (mp4, jpeg, etc) Java

Tags: java, binary, hex, compression

Anyway to get all of the binary from common filetypes like mp4, jpeg, etc.  I know I can do this with a hex editor, but I want to work with the binary in java for compression purposes.

Comment: You don't want to load it in an ide. You want to read it directly from source and streamprocess it. http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/02/java_tip_how_read_files_quickly

Comment: That link isn't loading for me. I'll try it again when I get back to my desktop, but in the meantime, could you explain how I'm reading the file from source within java?

Comment: Your question sounds like you be best off starting with the basics of I/O: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/streams.html